# Android: Adding a file to an SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, text-files

Within my application I am currently writing data realted to game sessions (e.g. score etc) to an SQLite database.

Throughout the game session I am also writing more detailed data to a text file.

I wish to attach this text file to my current SQLite database as another column.

I.e. the text file will be entered along with the other data entry about the game session.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

What data type would I use for entering in a text file, a String?

Below is code showing the creation of the current database. If any other info is needed just ask.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 10;

    // Database Name
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MeditationDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_SESSION = "sessionid";
    private static final String COL_GAMETITLE = "game";
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_MED = "avgmeditation";
    private static final String COL_MAX = "maxmeditation";
    private static final String COL_AVGATT = "avgattention";
    private static final String COL_MAXATT = "maxattention";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //VERY IMPORTANT: ALWAYS CHECK THAT THERE ARE SPACES AND COMMAS IN CORRECT PLACE IN CODE BELOW:

        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "(" + COL_SESSION
                + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " + COL_GAMETITLE + " STRING, "  + COL_NAME + " STRING, " + COL_MED + " INTEGER, "
                 + COL_MAX + " INTEGER, " + COL_AVGATT + " INTEGER, " + COL_MAXATT + " INTEGER, "  + COL_SCORE +  " INTEGER, " + COL_DATE + " STRING " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? Adding a column? Reading a file? Writing data into the database?

Comment: I am not sure what data type etc I would use for entering a text file?

Comment: ... what about TEXT? A text file is nothing but a big string, after all.

Comment: [Choose one](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Would string not be suitable then?

Comment: Assuming what you are asking is how to put the name of the text file (not the contents of the text file) in the database, just add another column of type TEXT. Even if you want to store the contents of the text file in the database, TEXT is what you want.

Comment: OK, yeah Well i would like to store the full text file in the database?

Comment: If you want to use the information contained under the text file for querying then by all means, break up the file and place it under a db context. However, if this is simply persistence, then create a file naming convention and keep the two datastore separate, simply referencing the text file name from the SQLite record.